# The best way to display 10k posts in WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 10k posts in my database. If I'm trying to display every o them by WP Query I have errors connected with the memory limit. I know I can make the memory limit bigger but I want to optimize the WP Query. What is the best way for it?

I thought about split the WP Query on smaller parts but I don't know how can I do it.

Daniel

Comment: Are you talking about displaying them all in one go? If so, _why_ - what user would ever be interested in looking at _that_ amount of data in one single heap?

Comment: The customer has to see all of the real estate on the front page (12 per page). I know it's very problematic but we have te search form which is searching in these 10k posts and after it, I'm building a query.

Comment: For example, you can try to use paginator.

Comment: _“(12 per page)”_ - so _not_ all of them in one go then, but with pagination. Show us some of the code you are actually using for this then, so that we can try to figure out where you did go wrong.

Comment: See here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query

Comment: Pagination, if you are trying to increase your memory for such requirements you are thinking it wrong i guess. As @CBroe no1 has any interest in viewing 10k in a single page. Would take sooooo much time just to load, imagine scrolling for so much time. The user would get tired really easy and quit

Comment: A scroll to load system could be a great approach instead of a regular pagination.

Comment: Thanks for every response. My page is using to search the flats and investments and I have to list every from them on the first screen with pagination as you mentioned above. The problem is with search because I'm getting the flats first and I'm checking which are meeting the requirements. After this operation, I'm taking only investments where the flats are meeting these requirements and the main problem is I'm building the query twice the time. I have to change the search script and make only one bigger query. When I will do it the problem will be no show again. Thank you for giving me advic